# Avoiding lag caused by hoisting

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I want to log 'tapped' and execute the HUD asap, but oauth_upload_photo is causing it to lag (apparently because of hoisting).  How can I snap the HUD instantly??

```
var submit_post = function submit_post(){

    console.log('tapped');

    // Show HUD
    plugins.navigationBar.hideRightButton();
    var hud = document.getElementById("hud");
    hud.style.display = 'block';    

    // Get the image
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    var imageURI = image.src;

    // Get the caption from the textarea
    var cap = document.getElementById('tar');
    var caption = cap.value;

    // Call upload photo
    oauth_upload_photo(imageURI,caption);

};
```

Comment: What does this have to do with hoisting? What exactly is "lagging"?

Comment: It's the declaration of the function that is hoisted, not the invocation of it. Read up more on hoisting. Lagging will most likely be down to other GUI work you have going on (of which your example doesn't show any).

Comment: When I comment out oauth_upload_photo,'tapped' is logged instantly. When I don't, there is a 1-2 second delay before 'tapped' is logged.  oauth_upload_photo is relatively complex (binary image conversion)

Comment: @ggwarpig: You'll probably only be able to solve it by running `oauth_upload_photo` inside a setTimeout` (with a *really* small timeout value) (but this is still unrelated to function hoisting :)).

Comment: @Matt no change when running it inside a setTimeout.  Appreciate the attempt at a solution though!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue (which needs a lot more explanation before we could understand what you're actually asking about) has nothing to do with javascript variable hoisting.  All hoisting does is cause variables to be defined at the top of the function,regardless of where their initial declaration is located in the function.  It doesn't change the execution order of any statements.

Also, in some browsers `console.log()` is not guaranteed to be completely synchronous and the display of the data in the log window is not necessarily immediate either.  There is sometimes a delay before it actually logs.  I don't know if this is caused by marshalling data across process boundaries, general repaint logic or some other internal implementation issue.

You may also want to change this:

```
var submit_post = function submit_post(){
```

to this:

```
var submit_post = function (){
```

or even this:

```
function submit_post() {
```

so you aren't double defining the same symbol.

Comment: FWIW, the "double define" will only be a problem in IE<9; in others it yeilds the advantage of not having an "anonymous function" in your callstack when trying to debug errors :P.

Comment: @Matt - why not just use a normal function definition here rather than a variable assignment?

Comment: `@`jfriend00: That'd be the best solution I guess :). I was meaning to clarify the sentence, rather than suggesting an alternative :).

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought hoisting was causing the order of execution to change.  thanks for clearing that up.  fixed the double define.  its unrelated to the log because the HUD is delayed as well.  Not sure what more there is to explain, the hud.style.display = 'block' executes MUCH faster when I comment out the oauth_upload_photo call.

Comment: @ggwarpig - I don't think the `hud.style.display = 'block'` executes faster when you comment out the oauth call - I just think the screen isn't updated until the current JS execution is done.  There are a couple ways around that.  You could execute the `oauth_upload_photo()` on a `setTimeout(oauth_upload_photo, 1)` or you could force a screen refresh before calling it.